# What does "knowledge" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the following paragraph in Andrew Vincent's *Nature of Political Theory*:

> In ancient Greek culture, theory was characteristically associated
> with observation. A *thea* was a spectacle; the one who observed the
> spectacle was a *theoros*. *Theoria* meant beholding a spectacle. Theory
> was thus envisaged as the intermediary between the event and the
> observer. It accounted for the event or practice. Theory was not
> separate from event. **Knowledge** was, in a sense, the unmediated event
> itself.

What does the author define **"knowledge"** mean in the context of the above paragraph?

Comment: "Knowledge was, ..., the unmediated event itself."

Comment: @JamesK what is the difference between the event and the unmediated event and the mediated event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means exactly what the dictionary says. Knowledge is acquired information or understanding. In your sample text, it seems that knowledge is being compared against *theory*.

The overall message of the text seems to be how close theory is to knowledge by showing the root meaning of theory to be the observation of something, and that "something" is the knowledge trying to be acquired.